# ATI friendly distro?

Tags: distribution-choice, laptop, ati, radeon

I've been researching on problems with ATI catalyst drivers and there is no fix as far as I can see. I have an ATI Radeon 7470m (HP Pavilion dm4). And I haven't managed to have a properly working distro.

Is there any Linux distro that behaves well with this card and allows me to have GNOME3 without burning my laptop? If there is not a solution yet this question should help new users to get a quick update :)

Comment: Have you tried [**Fedora**](https://fedoraproject.org/)? (I'm not sure whether it has the drivers you need, I'm just asking/giving a hint. Also, for battery life, check out [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html).)

Comment: I have Debian on a desktop with a ATI X1300 and free drivers, and I'm happy with my hw acceleration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should [burn your laptop](https://askubuntu.com/a/201835/1078):

> Your card is not supported by any driver, closed or open source.
>
> You need to use what is working for you at the moment and wait for AMD to start supporting your card via their drivers.

After screwing around with a HP/dv6 I vowed never to get ATI ever again (and mine even works).

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu forums are currently down but there is a thread over there titled: [AMD Radeon 7470M](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1965772). In that thread someone asked the following question:

```
Question:   Has anybody successfully run linux on a laptop with a AMD 
            Radeon HD 7470M?
Background: HP Pavilion dv7 with and AMD Radeon HD 7470M graf card
```

To which someone answered that they were able to use Linux Mint successfully with that hardware.

Also in the Linux Mint forums there was this thread titled: [Installing AMD Radeon Graphics Driver](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=121710). In this thread a user reported that they were able to use the "beta" version of the Catalyst drivers and they worked fine.

> I also have a Radeon video card from ATI (specifically, 7470M). I
>   downloaded the lastest stable driver and the beta one. I ended up
>   using the beta driver since it works seamlessly compared to the STABLE
>   one who literally screwed up my display until I removed it and
>   installed the beta driver.

If you go to the AMD website you can find the "beta" drivers available here, on a page titled: [AMD Catalyst™ 13.6 LINUX Beta Driver](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-6LINBetaDriver.aspx). The article is dated 5/29/2013 and is article #: RN-LN-B13.6.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However I think msw is right and it's all a myth. I will try it out. But after researching a bit it's a matter of getting another laptop asap and never again buying AMD hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Mageia OS support ATI Radeon Series 
http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=mageia